# How can I make my react navbar responsive

Tags: css, reactjs

My react app navbar goes out of proportion on mobile view, I have tried possible styles that could make it responsive and not successful.
Here is what my app looks like on [mobile view](https://imge.to/i/TdC21)

This is the [desktop view](https://imge.to/i/TdpcA)

This is the default styling

css

```
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.left-nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right-nav-menu {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's about how much elements can the navbar hold on a mobile view, to solve this problem, the default approach taken is to display a menu instead of the the regular list of tabs.

A good example of this usage.

[How TO - Responsive Top Navigation](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp).

PS: go to mobile view in your browser dev tools to see the difference in the example between the desktop and mobile views.